# react hooks setInterval,Why can it be modified for the first time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

> Why is it that the correct count value can be obtained in setinterval after the first click, and then the transformation does not occur again?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Demo1 = () => {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const onCountClick = () => {
    count += 1;
    setCount(count);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(count);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  console.log(count);
  return <button onClick={() => onCountClick()}>test</button>;
};
```

Comment: kindly improve your question, its not clear what are you trying for?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want to consult that when I click on the oncount click event, the first count value is modified, and the subsequent click will not have effect on setinterval polling. In particular, it is necessary to pay attention to the statement of "let" in let [count, setcount] = usestate (1).

Answer (score 1):

You are directly modifying the state. Instead do this:

```
setCount(count++)
```

Answer (score 0):

React doen't really handle `setInterval` that smoothly, you have to remember that when you put it in `componentDidMount` (`useEffect` with an empty dependencies' array), it builds its callback with the current values, then never updates.

Instead, put it inside `componentDidUpdate` (`useEffect` with relevant dependencies), so that it could have a chance to update. It boils down to actually clearing the old interval and building a new one.

```
const Demo1 = () => {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  let [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);
  const onCountClick = () => {
    count += 1;
    setCount(count);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setIntervalId(setInterval(() => {
      console.log(count);
    }, 1000));
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    setIntervalId(setInterval(() => {
      console.log(count);
    }, 1000));
  }, [count]);
  console.log(count);
  return <button onClick={() => onCountClick()}>test</button>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want to consult that when I click on the "onCountClick" event, the first count value is modified, and the subsequent click will not have effect on setinterval polling

Comment: That's why on `count` change you clear your previous interval and set a new, updated one.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that changing the value of state directly like `count += 1` is a bad approach, instead use `setCount(count + 1)` and you cannot console.log any value in the return statement instead use `{count}` to display the value on the screen instead of `console`.
The following code will increment the value of count on every click instance

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
    const onCountClick = () => {
      // count += 1;
      setCount(count + 1);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log(count);
      }, 1000);
    });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => onCountClick()}>test</button>;
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want to consult that when I click on the oncount click event, the first count value is modified, and the subsequent click will not have effect on setinterval polling. In particular, it is necessary to pay attention to the statement of "let" in let [count, setcount] = usestate (1).